# How can I dynamically parse UID in the ownerReference (Helm CHart)

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a simple helm chart with a Deployment and Job Object

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-parent
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ .Release.Name }}-parent
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ .Release.Name }}-parent
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: nginx:latest
          
          # Add other container configuration as needed
```

and the job object

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-job
  ownerReferences:
    - apiVersion: apps/v1
      blockOwnerDeletion: true
      controller: true
      kind: Deployment
      name: {{ .Release.Name }}-parent
      uid: $(kubectl get deployment my-release-parent -o jsonpath='{.metadata.uid}')
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ .Release.Name }}-job
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: busybox
          image: busybox:latest
      restartPolicy: Never
          # Add other container configuration as needed
      # Add other Job configuration as needed
```

I'm trying to dynamically parse the `UID` of the deployment object as the `onwnerReference` in the job manifest. Right now, if I deploy this chart, everything works fine except for the job that wont get deployed. When I remove the `ownerReference` from the job manifest, the `job` deploys perfectly, so I know the issue has to do with the way I parsed the `UID`..

I want a situation that whenever I delete my deployment, it deletes all the child resources.
See more: [onwerReference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/common-definitions/object-meta/#System)

i tried different ways to dynamically parse the UID, and this codes works if i directly run the commands after the deployment.

```
kubectl get deployment deploymentexample -o yaml | grep uid | cut -d ' ' -f 4

kubectl get deployment my-release-parent -o jsonpath='{.metadata.uid}'
```

Comment: IME it's very unusual to set `ownerReference` at all; even in actual code that creates objects, this is managed by the SDKs.  I'd also be surprised if you deleted the Deployment separately from the Helm chart, though.  Does `helm uninstall my-release` also uninstall the Job; is that enough for your use?

Comment: In principle the [`lookup`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/functions_and_pipelines/#using-the-lookup-function) function could find the Deployment, but this might not work if the Deployment and Job are part of the same chart.  This can lead to your chart having different behavior depending on what's installed in the cluster, which can make it hard to test and debug, so I tend to avoid this approach.

Comment: in my case, when the `deployment` is deleted, the jobs are left behind, thus, I need to include the `ownerReference` to the job manifest. If I manually get the UID for the deployment by running `kubectl get deployment my-release-parent -o jsonpath='{.metadata.uid}' ` and I hardcode it in my manifest, the `onwerReference` perfectly. I think there is a way to dynamically parse it to the `job` manifest.

Comment: When are you deleting the Deployment without uninstalling the whole chart?

Answer (score 0):

Use Helm [lookups](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/functions_and_pipelines/#using-the-lookup-function):

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-job
  {{- $parentDeployment := lookup "apps/v1" "Deployment" .Release.Namespace (printf "%s-parent" .Release.Name) }}
  {{- if $parentDeployment }}
  ownerReferences:
    - apiVersion: apps/v1
      blockOwnerDeletion: true
      controller: true
      kind: Deployment
      name: {{ .Release.Name }}-parent
      uid: {{ $parnetDeployment.metadata.uid }}
  {{- end }}
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ .Release.Name }}-job
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: busybox
          image: busybox:latest
      restartPolicy: Never
          # Add other container configuration as needed
      # Add other Job configuration as needed
```

But as menioned in commentaries to your question this won't work in case of `Deployment` and `Job` are deployed in the same Helm chart.

If jobs are created during `helm upgrade`, they already will have `ownerRefference` because during upgrade deployment already exists in a cluster.

---

Nevertheless, I think that [`Helm hooks`](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/#writing-a-hook) will work better for your project.

Example you can create a Job with following annotations:

```yaml
annotations:
  helm.sh/hook: post-install,post-upgrade
  helm.sh/hook-delete-policy: before-hook-creation
```

and get the dynamic job created after every install or upgrade operation.